# pipenv can't install requirements.txt. Error: ERROR: metadata generation failed

Tags: installation, dependencies, repository, pipenv, requirements.txt

I'm trying to install the following packages from requirements.txt for a cloned repository.

```
torch
openai
langchain
graphviz
langchain-visualizer
pydantic
wandb
pandas
spacy
textstat
transformers
google-search-results
```

I have the following pipfile and I have Python 3.10.4:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
openai = "*"
langchain = "*"
graphviz = "*"
dotenv = "*"
langchain-visualizer = "*"
pydantic = "*"
wandb = "*"
pandas = "*"
spacy = "*"
textstat = "*"
transformers = "*"
google-search-results = "*"
yaml = "*"
gitpython = "*"
torch = "*"
supervisor = "*"

[dev-packages]
ipykernel = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.10"
python_full_version = "3.10.10"
```

I'm getting the following warning and error:

```
  ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
  Pipfile.lock (aba59f) out of date, updating to (bceb64)...
  Locking [packages] dependencies...
  [=   ] Resolving dependencies...
  ERROR:pip.subprocessor:[present-rich] python setup.py egg_info exited with 1
  [ResolutionFailure]:   File
  ..............................
  ..............................
  ..............................
  [ResolutionFailure]:       raise ResolutionFailure(message=str(e))
  [pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be 
  resolved. 
  You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  You can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv 
  graph to inspect the situation.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
  ERROR: metadata generation failed
```

I have tried pipenv lock --clear. I tried pip install -r requirements.txt under the pipenv activated environment, but libraries aren't accessible for the repository files. I have used pipenv graph to check the versions, but all installations are higher and within the version limit. What's wrong with the installation or my sub-dependencies? How can I make the repository files access the libraries using pipenv or pip?